# How to index a pdf file in Elasticsearch 5.0.0 with ingest-attachment plugin?

Tags: pdf, elasticsearch, plugins, attachment, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I read here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/mapper-attachments.html that the mapper-attachments plugin is deprecated in elasticsearch 5.0.0.

I now try to index a pdf file with the new ingest-attachment plugin and upload the attachment.

What I've tried so far is

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/pdf' -XPOST localhost:9200/test/1 -d @/cygdrive/c/test/test.pdf
```

but I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400}
```

I would expect that the pdf file will be indexed and uploaded. What am I doing wrong?

I also tested Elasticsearch 2.3.3 but the mapper-attachments plugin is not valid for this version and I don't want to use any older version of Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to make sure you have created your *ingest* pipeline with:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "data",
        "indexed_chars" : -1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can make a *PUT* not *POST* to your index using the pipeline you've created.

```
PUT my_index/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment
{
  "data": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0="
}
```

In your example, should be something like:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/pdf' -XPUT localhost:9200/test/1?pipeline=attachment -d @/cygdrive/c/test/test.pdf
```

Remembering that the PDF content must be base64 encoded.

Hope it will help you.

**Edit 1**
Please make sure to read these, it helped me a lot:

[Elastic Ingest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)

[Ingest Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest.html)

[Ingest Presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/elastic/ingest-node-re-indexer-et-enrichir-des-documents-dans-elasticsearch-softshake-2016)

**Edit 2**

Also, you must have **ingest-attachment** plugin installed.

```
./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

**Edit 3**

Please, before you create your *ingest processor* (attachment), create your *index*, *map* with the fields you will use and make sure you have the **data** field in your *map* (same name of the "field" in your attachment processor), so ingest will process and fullfill your **data** field with your pdf content.

I inserted the *indexed_chars* option in the ingest processor, with *-1* value, so you can index large pdf files.

**Edit 4**

The mapping should be something like that:

```
PUT my_index
{ 
    "mappings" : { 
        "my_type" : { 
            "properties" : { 
                "attachment.data" : { 
                    "type": "text", 
                    "analyzer" : "brazilian" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

In this case, I use the *brazilian* filter, but you can remove that or use your own.

Comment: Why do you need a mapping for the data field?  Doesn't the pipeline pick up the data field and process it without it having to be explicitly mapped?  What would this mapping look like?

Comment: @bjlevine you do not need to map the field actually... the processor will create an inside (of your processor) the field. But sometimes you need to have some filter like the updated answer. hope it helps

Comment: I've fought a lot with Ingest Attachment plugin. It can't be used in production. I use Ambar (http://ambar.rdseventeen.com) as a solid solution for stroing and searching through documents

Comment: @SochiX sure we can use it in production, as it is in production in several cases. I myself has a project running in production mode and running pretty well. not bit deal, but there are 1K files, over 2Gb data and search results less than 1 second.

Comment: @Evert thank you for your comment. But in my case I have 3 000 000 files and total size of index is 268 Gb.  Ingest attachment just eats all the RAM when it tries to proccess the file larger then 40 MB. That's why I switched to Ambar.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about Ingest Attachment plugin problems. Check it out: [Ingest Attachment Plugin for ElasticSearch: Should You Use It?](https://blog.ambar.cloud/ingest-attachment-plugin-for-elasticsearch-should-you-use-it/)

Comment: @SochiX you are the developer of Ambar, nice, I understand your enthusiasm. I will give it a try, but confess... I am really happy with ES + Ingest. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, I get how to create the pipeline and am able to push a document to my index. However, what if my pdf was to be a stored in a field of my django object. How do I index other fields and this pdf?

Comment: @RishabhRanawat as in my **Edit 4** you just enter the properties (fields) you need, as of the official documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html, and when indexing, just fill your post with the data as needed. Hope it was of help.

Comment: when using `XPUT` to post pdf i get  `{"error":"Content-Type header [application/pdf] is not supported","status":406}` any suggestions?

Comment: @Augustas are you using Curl? Which version of es you are using? I suggest post a new question and post your code so we could help you better.

Comment: How do you query this document ?

Comment: Hi @IlyaP, Did you find the solution to your problem for huge data?

Comment: @sushilprj yep, try Ambar!

Comment: @IlyaP, Ambar looks great! How does it compare with https://github.com/opensemanticsearch ?

Comment: Hi, @Stacky it's more lightweight I guess and easy to setup/host

Comment: @IlyaP I created a question on Ambar github to avoid hijacking this thread. Could you comment? Thanks! https://github.com/RD17/ambar/issues/287

Comment: Good tips you have provided!