# How to index a pdf file using Elasticsearch ingest-attachment plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-plugin

I have to implement a full-text based search in a pdf document using `Elasticsearch` ingest plugin. I'm getting an empty hit array when I'm trying to search the word `someword` in the pdf document.

```
//Code for creating pipeline

PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
    "description" : "Extract attachment information",
    "processors" : [
      {
        "attachment" : {
        "field" : "data",
        "indexed_chars" : -1
        }
      }
    ]
}

//Code for creating the index

PUT my_index/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment
{
   "filename" : "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\bh1.pdf",
   "title" : "Quick",
   "data": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0="

}

//Code for searching the word in pdf 

GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
      "data" : {
        "query" : "someword"
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you open the PDF in a PDF viewer, are you able to search for "someword" in it and find a match?

Comment: @Alcanzar Yeah it searches for the word.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861279/how-to-index-a-pdf-file-in-elasticsearch-5-0-0-with-ingest-attachment-plugin -- note that your PUT statement is putting a specific "data" for the file.  You need to use curl or something like that to pass the specific file data.  The "data" you are putting in is `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` -- if you search for Lorem, you'd find a result

Comment: @Alcanzar I verified by searching for Lorem by running the GET on Kibana dashboard. But still there are not hits.

Comment: @Alcanzar Can you pls tell me the theory behind the elasticsearch indexing unstructered data like pdf files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you index your document with the second command by passing the Base64 encoded content, the document then looks like this:

```
        {
           "filename": "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\bh1.pdf",
           "data": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0=",
           "attachment": {
              "content_type": "application/rtf",
              "language": "ro",
              "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
              "content_length": 28
           },
           "title": "Quick"
        }
```

So your query needs to look into the `attachment.content` field and not the `data` one (which only serves the purpose of sending the raw content during indexing)

Modify your query to this and it will work:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "attachment.content": {         <---- change this
            "query": "lorem"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

PS: Use `POST` instead of `GET` when sending a payload

Comment: Any idea on how can we convert a pdf file to base64 encoded file using elastic search ?

Comment: I think this should be a new question as it is unrelated to this one.

Comment: Why did you use POST instead of GET ? The later works fine for me

Comment: It depends on the HTTP client you're using, but you should **NEVER** send a payload via GET (= not HTTP compliant). See a more detailed example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795053/es-keeps-returning-every-document/34796014#34796014

Comment: @Ashley afaik that is done before data is sent to elastic search, so you do the conversion with whatever method exists in the programming language you are using.