# Index PDF with Elasticsearch Page by page Vs using ingest plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am doing a project to index a bunch of PDF documents, for this task I've chosen Elasticsearch, as it is based on Apache Lucene. 
Checking out several docs

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.3/using-ingest-attachment.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html#ingest-processors

and Stackoverflow questions: 
[How to index a pdf file in Elasticsearch 5.0.0 with ingest-attachment plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861279/how-to-index-a-pdf-file-in-elasticsearch-5-0-0-with-ingest-attachment-plugin?rq=1)

In terms of performance, storage space,and effectiveness what would be a better approach, to use the ingest plugin as described, or to parse the pdf and store every page, two, or three (this can be a changing parameter) and put them in a separate document ?

Comment: We got into same requirments, please share your inputs

Comment: I also have a similar problem to solve, do let us know if you found any efficient solution.